# Make arguments as an optional in an abstract function

Tags: php

Lets say I have these classes:

```php
abstract class Car
{
    abstract public function handle(array $data);
}

class CarA extends Car 
{
    public function handle(array $data)
    {
        echo $data['color'];
    }
}

$car= new CarA();
// Here I can pass args as an array
$car->handle([
    "color" => "white"
]);
```

Which works fine.

### The problem:

Now I don't want to pass any args

```php
class CarB extends Car 
{
    public function handle()
    {
        echo 'CarB';
    }
}

$car= new CarB();
// Here I dont wnat to pass any args, I just want to call the method.
$car->handle();
```

Which doesn't work. I face an error: `must be compatible with`

What I want?

I want the 'handle' function to work **only when array data is passed or none**.

Comment: Have you tried `handle(array $data = null)`? Of course inside the function you need to check if the value was passed.

Comment: Method signatures should be same for both. Try `public function handle(array $data = [])` or replace inheritance for composition

Comment: Thats the issue, I don't want to write `public function handle(array $data)` In CarB. I just want it simply  `public function handle()`

Comment: `abstract public function handle(? array $data=null ) ` , and extenders must have the same signature. Then you can $car->handle(); ... although you seem to want a variable-geometry function, which i find odd.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @jacki360, the closest you will get is to use [func_get_args()](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.func-get-args.php).

```
abstract class Car
{
    abstract public function handle();
}

class CarA extends Car 
{
    public function handle()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        if ( count($args) && is_array($args[0]) ) {
            $data = $args[0];
            echo $data['color'];
        }
    }
}
class CarB extends Car
{
    public function handle()
    {
        echo self::Class . "\n";
    }
}

$car= new CarA();
// Here I can pass args as an array
$car->handle([
    "color" => "white"
]);
$car2 = new CarB;
$car2->handle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function must have the same signature, so what you can try is making the function without argument: handle()
and when you need an argument just pass it when calling the method and retrieve them with 
[func_get_args](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.func-get-args.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Car {
    abstract public function handle();
    public $data;
    public $color;

    public function setArguments(Array $arguments, $recursive = false) {
        $this->data = $recursive === true ? $this->data : array();

        // Do additional formatting here if needed
        foreach ($arguments as $key => $argument) {
            if (is_array($argument)) {
                $this->setArguments($argument, true);
            } else {
                $this->data[$key] = $argument;
            }
        }

        $this->setColor();
    }

    public function setColor() {
        $this->color = !empty($this->data['color']) ? $this->data['color'] : 'Any';
    }
}

class CarA extends Car {
    public function handle() {
        $this->setArguments(func_get_args());
        echo 'Color: ' . $this->color;
    }
}

class CarB extends Car {
    public function handle() {
        $this->setArguments(func_get_args());
        echo 'Color: ' . $this->color;
    }
};

$carA = new CarA();
$carA->handle(array(
    'color' => 'Color1'
));

$carB = new CarB();
$carB->handle();
$carB->handle(array(
    'color' => 'Color2'
));
```